# Using mouse click event to get ListViewItem text

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to use listview to populate it with data and then use mouseclick event to fill some textboxes with data. I looked up an example in msdn:

```
ListViewItem theClickedOne = listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
ListViewItem theClickedtwo = listView1.FocusedItem;
if (theClickedOne != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(theClickedtwo.ToString());
    //do your thing here.
    //there is a reference to the listview item we clicked on
    //in our theClickedOne variable.
}
```

but I couldn't think about a way to use it in order to differentiate the listviewitems I use since the fist Column in my program is the same and it will only give me a string with it's name(first Column).I want to have something similar to next example but for treeview.

```
void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(Object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);
}
```

Comment: When it comes to differentiating UI elements, I usually set the Tag property of the element. Have a look into that.

Comment: "I want to have something similar to next example but for treeview." -- What? Do you want to do this with a `ListView` control or a `TreeView`? Most of your post, until this last statement, seems to say `ListView`.

Comment: I know,in my code I also use treeview and mouseclick event and it was easier for me to get how to use it and identify strings.I tought that listview would be the same and it's diffrent.

Comment: In addition to the Tags you can also add subitems and use their Texts; they are only visible in Veew=Details mode..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When populating you `ListView`, set the `Tag` property of the items, e.g.

```
newItem.Tag = "Item 1";
```

The `Tag` property has type `object`, so you can use anything you want here to identify the item. When handling the mouse click event simply check the `Tag` value again:

```
if((string)(clickedItem.Tag) == "Item 1")
{
    // do stuff for this specific item.
}
```

Comment: I used tag to pass it as a pointer to class like this: `Class p=(Class)(theClickedtwo.Tag);` and it worked great.